# Jquery Event Click After Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, click, jquery-post

I'm with a problem in my code, when I do a ajax post, the click event stop working, here is my code:

```js
$("#register_button").click(function(){
   if(condittion_1){
      code...
   }
   else{
     my ajax post...
   }
}
```

The problem is, after the ajax post, the click button event stop working. I made a test, I removed the ajax from the Else, and put out it, the ajax post was working and the button click event was normal, but when I put it in else, the click event stop working...Please, I need some help =(

Comment: Are you replacing the HTML containing `#register_button` in your AJAX post? BTW, revealing your if-else block would be helpful.

Comment: <form> <div id="register_button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 127px;">Register</div>
     </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not post all your detail code so I could only take a guess.
I think in success function of ajax post, a part of html on your page, include button *#register_button*, will be updated. In that case, inside success function of ajax post, you need to re-bind click event for button *#register_button*.
You could try to update your code as following:

```
function handleClickEvent() {
    $("#register_button").click(function(){
       if(condittion_1){
          code...
       }
       else{
         $.post( "example.php", function() {
            // other code of success function 
            ....
            // call function to re-bind click event
            handleClickEvent();

         })
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How Do I re-bind it?

Comment: The ajax is working, everything work's perfect, but the button stop working after the call...

Comment: You could try  re-bind click event by call **$("#register_button").click(...)**. You could consider to separate code that binding click event to another function, then just call this function inside document ready and success function of ajax post.

Comment: <form> <div id="register_button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 127px;">Register</div>
     </form>

Comment: I've edited my answer. To re-bind click event, please try to update code as I've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: I solved the problem, I have no idea about why it was not working.

I had a variable named  var dt_nascimento = $('#dt_nascimento');
And I realized that both had the same name, so I changed de var name to data_nascimento and it worked perfectly.

Thank you to give some help (;

Comment: I've created an example at link https://jsfiddle.net/w6a1e28y/  Please check it. You could try to comment line 15 of javascript (not call binding after update html content), then you will see click event will not fire anymore.